# What is wrong in this python backtester?

Tags: programming, backtesting, python

I am trying to write a simple backtester using python and pandas. I have reused the code of [Michael halls moore's](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quantstart/media/powerpoint/an-introduction-to-backtesting.pdf) pandas backtester. I rewrote the programme because first I want to understand how backtesting works and secondly I found (for me) the original code hard to understand.

This is the rewrote code

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

#download data

start=datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
end=datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)

ibm = DataReader('IBM',  'yahoo', start ,end )

#technical analysis library
#https://www.quantopian.com/posts/technical-analysis-indicators-without-talib-code

def MA(df, n):  
    MA = pd.Series(pd.rolling_mean(df, n), name = 'MA_' + str(n))  
    df =MA
    return df

def gen_signals(df,fast=10,slow=30):
    signals=pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
    signals['signal']=0
    signals['price']=df

    #fast slow moving average
    signals['fast']=MA(signals['price'],fast)
    signals['slow']=MA(signals['price'],slow)

    #if fast sma is greater than slow sma then 1 else 0
    signals['signal']=np.where(signals['fast']>signals['slow'],1,0)

    #taking difference to genrate actual trading order
    signals['positions']=signals['signal'].diff()
    return signals


def gen_positions(self):
    positions=pd.DataFrame(index=self.index).fillna(0.0)
    positions['position']=10*self['signal'] #10 shares/signal
    return positions

def backtest(positions,price,initial_capital=10000):
    #creating protfolio
    portfolio =positions*price['price']    
    pos_diff=positions.diff()

    #creating holidings
    portfolio['holidings']=(positions*price['price']).sum(axis=1)
    portfolio['cash']=initial_capital-(pos_diff*price['price']).sum(axis=1).cumsum()

    #full account equity
    portfolio['total']=portfolio['cash']+ portfolio['holidings']
    portfolio['return']=portfolio['total'].pct_change()
    return portfolio

#signal generation
sig=gen_signals(ibm['Close'],fast=5,slow=25)
sig.head(3)

#positon genration
pos=gen_positions(sig)
pos.tail(3)

#backtesting
re=backtest(pos,sig)
re.head()
```

But the out put result is this

```
            2011-12-30 00:00:00  position  holidings  cash  total  return  
Date                                                                       
2000-01-03                  NaN       NaN        NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  
2000-01-04                  NaN       NaN        NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  
2000-01-05                  NaN       NaN        NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  
2000-01-06                  NaN       NaN        NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN  
2000-01-07                  NaN       NaN        NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Any idea why its happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting cross-product instead of value by value multiplication in this line:

> portfolio = positions*price['price']

I suspect you need something like that (use .position filed from your dataframe) :

```
portfolio = positions['position']*price['price']    
pos_diff = positions['position'].diff()

#creating holidings
portfolio['holidings'] = (positions['position']*price['price']).sum()
portfolio['cash'] = initial_capitalpos_diff*price['price']).sum().cumsum()
....
```